# Orthogonal projection of a point onto a line in processing?

Tags: java, math, vector, processing, orthogonal

I have a line segment and a circle in my processing sketch. I want the center of the circle, point q, to find the closest point, p, on the line segment and the circle will move towards it. 
I'm not quite sure how to code this (in processing), so any suggestions would be great! Thanks! 
This is my code so far:

```
int xPos1 = 200;
int yPos1 = 200;
int xp1 = 50;
int yp1 = 50;
int xp2 = 350;
int yp2 = 50;

void setup() {
    size(400, 400); 
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(xp1, yp1, xp2, yp2);
    strokeWeight(1);
}

void draw() {
    drawCircle();
}

void drawCircle() {
    fill(50, 120, 120);
    //circle
    ellipse(xPos1, yPos1, 75, 75); 
    //circle center
    ellipse(xPos1, yPos1, 7, 7);  
    fill(255);
    text("Q", xPos1 + 15, yPos1 + 5);
    fill(50, 120, 120);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection of a point onto a line is as follows:

Start with a line of the form x = a + t * n and a point p.

---

The vector compontent representing the nearest point on the line from the point p is:

(a - p) - ((a - p) dot n)n

so we have: p + (a - p) - ((a - p) dot n)n

after some simplification we have:
a - ((a - p) dot n)n

---

Note that ((a - p) dot n) n is the vector component that represents the position along the line from the nearest point to the beginning (i.e. from nearest point to p back to a)

Let's use `PVector`s to make life a bit easier.

```
PVector p = new PVector(200, 200);
PVector a = new PVector(50, 50);
PVector b = new PVector(350, 50);
PVector n = new PVector(350, 50); // |p2 - p1|

void setup() {
    size(400, 400); 
    strokeWeight(2);
    strokeWeight(1);

    // initialize our normalized (unit length) line direction
    n.sub(a);
    n.normalize();
}

void draw() {
    drawCircle();
}

PVector getNearestPointOnLine(PVector p, PVector a, PVector n){
    // the notation turns the computation inside out,
    // but this is equivalent to the above equation
    PVector q = PVector.mult(n, -PVector.sub(a, p).dot(n));
    q.add(a);
    return q;
}

void drawCircle() {
    // lets draw everything here where we can see it
    background(255, 255, 255);
    line(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);

    fill(50, 120, 120);
    //circle

    // NOTE: this may require hooking up a mouse move event handler
    p.x = mouseX;
    p.y = mouseY;
    PVector q = getNearestPointOnLine(p, a, n);

    ellipse(q.x, q.y, 75, 75); 
    //circle center
    ellipse(q.x, q.y, 7, 7);  
    fill(0); // make text visible on white background
    text("Q", q.x + 15, q.y + 5);
    //fill(50, 120, 120);
}
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation

Comment: Note that the point q will still appear beyond either end of the line segment, i.e. there are no "bounds" checks applied here.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.

Comment: Something I am looking for as well though is the circle moving towards whatever the closest point is on the line segment. Like we see the circle move. Any thoughts about how to do that would be great!

Comment: You can use the same vector formulation for that where t is a value from 0-1 and n is the normalized vector in the direction from the ball to the nearest point (i.e. norm(q - p) using the variables we already have).  The wikipedia article describes each vector component as one works through the formula. :)  For example when t is 0 then the above results in the ball being at the point p, when t is 1 the ball would be at point q.

Comment: If you need help working out how to animate the ball in that case, just ask another question.  Post a link to it here if you don't get a quick response, I'll be able to look at it after work.

Comment: I had this other sketch I was working on and it's a part of the new question about how to animate the ball- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252964/how-to-move-a-circle-across-a-line-in-processing

Answer (score 0):

*If you need implementation in Javafx*

#### vv

AB is the line. 
P is a point close to line. 
M is the point on the line that is closest to P.

```java
  public static Point findPointMOnLineClosestToGivenPointP(Point vector_A, Point vector_B, Point vector_P) {
    Point vector_AB = vector_B.subtract(vector_A);
    Point vector_AP = vector_P.subtract(vector_A);
    double distance_AM = vector_AB.dotProduct(vector_AP) / vector_AB.magnitude();
    Point vector_AM = vector_AB.normalize().multiply(distance_AM);
    Point vector_M = vector_A.add(vector_AM);
    return vector_M;
  }
```

*the `Point` class is just the same as `javafx.geometry.Point2D` class, it just I renamed it...*

---

*(Following are not important)*

#### test case & compare

(This produce same result as the other answer's `getNearestPointOnLine()`, similar Math formula.)

```java
package com.redfrog.trafficsm;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.Random;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.redfrog.trafficsm.model.Point;
import com.redfrog.trafficsm.util.MathUtil;

import processing.core.PVector;

class SimpleTest {

  Random random = new Random(111);

  @Test
  public void test_getNearestPointOnLine() {
    float bound = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      float f_x;
      float f_y;
      f_x = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
      f_y = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
      Point point_A = new Point(f_x, f_y);
      PVector pvector_A = new PVector(f_x, f_y);

      f_x = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
      f_y = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
      Point point_B = new Point(f_x, f_y);
      PVector pvector_B = new PVector(f_x, f_y);
      PVector pvector_N = pvector_B.sub(pvector_A).normalize();

      f_x = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
      f_y = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
      Point point_P = new Point(f_x, f_y);
      PVector pvector_P = new PVector(f_x, f_y);

      Point point_M = MathUtil.findPointMOnLineClosestToGivenPointP(point_A, point_B, point_P);
      PVector pvector_M = MathUtil.getNearestPointOnLine(pvector_P, pvector_A, pvector_N);

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println(point_M);
      System.out.println(pvector_M);

      int scale = 2;
      System.out.println(MathUtil.round(point_M.getX(), scale));
      System.out.println(MathUtil.round(pvector_M.x, scale));
      System.out.println(MathUtil.round(point_M.getY(), scale));
      System.out.println(MathUtil.round(pvector_M.y, scale));
      assertEquals(MathUtil.round(point_M.getX(), scale), MathUtil.round(pvector_M.x, scale));
      assertEquals(MathUtil.round(point_M.getY(), scale), MathUtil.round(pvector_M.y, scale));
    }

  }

}
```

```java
package com.redfrog.trafficsm.util;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

import com.redfrog.trafficsm.model.Point;

import processing.core.PVector;

public class MathUtil {

  public static double round(double value, int scale) {
    return round(value, scale, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN); // 
  }

  public static double round(double value, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    return new BigDecimal(value).setScale(scale, roundingMode).doubleValue(); // 
  }

  // ############

  public static Point findPointMOnLineClosestToGivenPointP(Point vector_A, Point vector_B, Point vector_P) {
    Point vector_AB = vector_B.subtract(vector_A);
    Point vector_AP = vector_P.subtract(vector_A);
    double distance_AM = vector_AB.dotProduct(vector_AP) / vector_AB.magnitude();
    Point vector_AM = vector_AB.normalize().multiply(distance_AM);
    Point vector_M = vector_A.add(vector_AM);
    return vector_M;
  }

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238017/orthogonal-projection-of-a-point-onto-a-line-in-processing
  public static PVector getNearestPointOnLine(PVector p, PVector a, PVector n) {
    // the notation turns the computation inside out,
    // but this is equivalent to the above equation
    PVector q = PVector.mult(n, -PVector.sub(a, p).dot(n));
    q.add(a);
    return q;
  }
}
```

#### visualization in Javafx

```java
package com.redfrog.note;

import java.util.Random;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.AtomicDouble;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import processing.core.PVector;

public class TestAppJavafxBoot extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    AnchorPane pane_JfxRoot = new AnchorPane();

    AnchorPane panel_SemanticRoot = new AnchorPane();
    pane_JfxRoot.getChildren().add(panel_SemanticRoot);

    final double opacity = 0.9;

    panel_SemanticRoot.setLayoutX(350);
    panel_SemanticRoot.setLayoutY(350);

    Random random = new Random(111);

    float bound = 100;

    float f_x;
    float f_y;

    f_x = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
    f_y = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
    Point2D point_A = new Point2D(f_x, f_y);
    PVector pvector_A = new PVector(f_x, f_y);

    final Circle circle = new Circle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(circle);
    circle.setRadius(3);
    circle.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, opacity));
    circle.setCenterX(f_x);
    circle.setCenterY(f_y);

    f_x = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
    f_y = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
    Point2D point_B = new Point2D(f_x, f_y);
    PVector pvector_B = new PVector(f_x, f_y);
    PVector pvector_N = pvector_B.sub(pvector_A).normalize();

    final Circle circle_02 = new Circle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(circle_02);
    circle_02.setRadius(3);
    circle_02.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0, opacity));
    circle_02.setCenterX(f_x);
    circle_02.setCenterY(f_y);

    f_x = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
    f_y = random.nextFloat(-bound, bound);
    Point2D point_P = new Point2D(f_x, f_y);
    PVector pvector_P = new PVector(f_x, f_y);

    final Circle circle_03 = new Circle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(circle_03);
    circle_03.setRadius(3);
    circle_03.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255, opacity));
    circle_03.setCenterX(f_x);
    circle_03.setCenterY(f_y);

    Point2D point_M = MathUtil.findPointMOnLineClosestToGivenPointP(point_A, point_B, point_P);
    PVector pvector_M = MathUtil.getNearestPointOnLine(pvector_P, pvector_A, pvector_N);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(point_M);

    final Circle circle_04 = new Circle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(circle_04);
    circle_04.setRadius(3);
    circle_04.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 255, 255, opacity));
    circle_04.setCenterX(point_M.getX());
    circle_04.setCenterY(point_M.getY());

    final Circle circle_05 = new Circle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(circle_05);
    circle_05.setRadius(3);
    circle_05.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0, opacity));
    circle_05.setCenterX(pvector_M.x);
    circle_05.setCenterY(pvector_M.y);


    Scene scene = new Scene(pane_JfxRoot, 950, 750);
    primaryStage.setTitle("DDD");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

  }
}
```