# How to move a circle across a line in processing?

Tags: java, math, vector, processing

I have a line segment and a circle in a processing sketch. In the sketch the circle finds the closest point on the line segment and another line is created to show that closest point. I want the circle to move across this line towards the closest point.
Also I want the circle to find the closest point on the line segment itself, but my sketch right now acts as though the line goes on forever. Any help is appreciated.

```
float x1,y1,x2,y2;
float cx,cy;
float x4,y4;

void setup() {
   size(600,600);
}

void init() {
   x1 = (int)random(100,500);
   y1 = (int)random(100,500);
   x2 = (int)random(100,500);
   y2 = (int)random(100,500);
   cx = (int)random(100,500);
   cy = (int)random(100,500);   
}   

void draw() {
   background(60);
   init();
   stroke(220);
   line(x1,y1,x2,y2);
   noFill();
   ellipse(cx,cy,50,50);
   noStroke();
   fill(220,20,20);//red- center of circle
   ellipse(cx,cy,8,8);
   // calculate the point
   float k = ((y2-y1) * (cx-x1) - (x2-x1) * (cy-y1)) / 
        ((y2-y1)*(y2-y1) + (x2-    x1)*(x2-x1));
   float x4 = cx - k * (y2-y1);
   float y4 = cy + k * (x2-x1);
   fill(20,20,220); //blue - point on line segment
   ellipse(x4,y4, 8,8);
   stroke(0);
   line(cx,cy,x4,y4);
   noLoop();
}

void keyPressed() { 
   loop(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two points, you can use the [`lerp()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) function to get a series of points between them.

> Calculates a number between two numbers at a specific increment. The `amt` parameter is the amount to interpolate between the two values where 0.0 equal to the first point, 0.1 is very near the first point, 0.5 is half-way in between, etc. The lerp function is convenient for creating motion along a straight path and for drawing dotted lines.

You can create a variable that you use as the `amt` argument between multiple calls to the `draw()` function. Then just increase that variable over time to move the point, and draw your circle there.